# what is alternative for unavailable tag for model in star micronics

Tags: ios, swift, printing, thermal-printer

I'm using starMicronics SDK for printing a slip. I'm facing the issue that actionPrintText(_ content: String) tag is used for printing the text but this is not available in TSP100IIIBI series
so what is the alternative for this tag that will work on TSP100IIIBI MOdel https://star-m.jp/products/s_print/sdk/starxpand/manual/en/ios-swift/api-reference/star-xpand-command/printer-builder/action-print-text.html

Comment: From the looks of the documentation that model printer isn't supported by the StarXPand API.  You would need to use the `print` Method of `StarPrinter` to send data to the printer

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you for the reply. The way I found is, to convert the slip into an image and set it into "actionPrintImage". This tag works for all printer models.